# Listing specific data in Query

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm learning databases and I have a question: How can I list all the students that study in a specific school using joins?

My table is as follows:

```
X:schoolName(PK), SchoolAddress, SchoolTelephoneNumber
Y:schoolName(FK),StudentName,StudentNumber
```

How can i find out all the students name that study in 'London School' including there StudentNumber, SchoolAddress?

Comment: Seriously you you first try to understand joins - googled mysql/joins and got this http://www.sitepoint.com/understanding-sql-joins-mysql-database/ (probably 1 of 1000's of articles)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
  SELECT 
  Students.StudentName,
  Students.StudentNumber,
  Schools.SchoolAddress 
FROM
  XSchools 
  INNER JOIN YStudents 
    ON Schools.schoolName = Students.schoolName 
WHERE Schools.schoolName = 'London School'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
  StudentName,
  StudentNumber,
  SchoolAddress 
FROM
  X
  JOIN Y
WHERE  Y.schoolName = 'London School'
```